# Не работает ServerSocket на Heroku

Tags: java, сокет, heroku

## Никакой реакции.Приложение деплоится.Но на клиенте ошибки при подключении.

## Также делал проверку на PING , чтобы быть уверенным в свободности портов, но ничего не происходит.

Статистика Ping для 54.217.217.151:
    Пакетов: отправлено = 5, получено = 0, потеряно = 5
    (100% потерь)

Весь код :

```
public class Server implements Runnable{
    ServerSocket socket=null;
    Socket socket2=null;
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Thread t = new Thread(new Server());
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            socket = new ServerSocket(55519);    
            socket2 = socket.accept();
            DataOutputStream dt = new DataOutputStream(new ObjectOutputStream(socket2.getOutputStream()));
            while(true){           

                dt.write(21312333);

            }    

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } catch (HeadlessException e) {


        } 
    }

}
```

А вот клиентский код :

```
package paket;


public class Client{
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        Socket s = new Socket("appname.herokuapp.com",55519);
        DataInputStream dtinput = new DataInputStream(new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream()));

         if(s.isConnected()){

             System.out.println("isConnected");
             System.out.println(dtinput.read());

             dtinput.close();
             s.close();

         }
    }


}
```

Procfile :

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Server
```

Exceptions :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at paket.Client.main(Client.java:19)
```

heroku-logs :
   только я пару раз открывал в браузере последние логи возможно из-за этого.

```
2017-09-19T11:31:45.332460+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-09-19T12:13:58.934934+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-09-19T12:14:02.839320+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Server`
2017-09-19T12:14:05.822492+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2017-09-19T12:14:05.838386+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
2017-09-19T12:15:32.950794+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
2017-09-19T12:15:32.950794+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2017-09-19T12:15:33.146013+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2017-09-19T12:15:33.158716+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-09-19T12:51:11.586463+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sever-elektro.herokuapp.com request_id=34d9a6c0-c152-46fe-9c81-9d29c49e916d fwd="185.117.148.44" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-09-19T12:51:12.590940+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sever-elektro.herokuapp.com request_id=36a4b2c9-6afb-4c7c-b36d-da6063b0a570 fwd="185.117.148.44" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: что пишет heroku logs?

Comment: @Roman Bortnikov добавил

Comment: еще прочитал вот эту страницу..похоже сокеты так нельзя использовать. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574085/deploy-simple-server-code-to-heroku